# Big O notation for Ruby methods?

Tags: c, ruby, time-complexity

How can I find the complexity of a Ruby method?

For example [length](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html)? If I look at the source code, I see this:

```
               static VALUE
rb_ary_length(VALUE ary)
{
    long len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    return LONG2NUM(len);
}
```

But I don't know how to read that in order to find the Big O notation.

Comment: Why is this tagged c? Ruby is written in c?

Comment: It is implemented in C.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Yes, Ruby is written in C.

Comment: No, it is not. *One* of the many implementations of Ruby is written in C. Others are written in Java. Or C#. Or Ruby. Or RPython. Or NQP. And they may have different implementations of said method.

Answer (score 7):

There is no maintained list of theoretical complexities of Ruby methods. Of interest to you is `minitest/benchmark`, which is used like this:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/benchmark'

class TestFoobar < Minitest::Benchmark
  def setup
    @foo_arrays = ( 1 .. 10_000 ).map { |n| [ 42 ] * n }
    # Because default benchmarking range is [1, 10, 100, 1_000, 10_000]
  end

  def bench_foo_size
    assert_performance_constant 0.99 do |n| @foo_arrays[ n ].size end
  end
end
```

If you run the above test, you can actually see that the performance of `Array#size` method is constant. If you change `#bench_foo_size` to:

```
def bench_foo_size
  assert_performance_linear 0.99 do |n| @foo_arrays[ n ].size end
end
```

The test will actually fail, because `Array#size` is not linear, but sublinear. `minitest/benchmark` is flexible and you can apply it to your own code as well as to built-in assets.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the relevant information from that. You have to look into the source of `RARRAY_LEN` and `LONG2NUM`.

A simple way to estimate the complexity of a method is to run benchmarks with arguments that differ along the dimension you are interested in, and plot that on a graph.

Answer (score 2):

It is just `O(1)` for the `length` method. The length of an array is stored in a variable and can be returned without further calculations.

How to find out? By reading the source code and analysing the implementation and algorithms.

Comment: I thought there would be some resource that would give the complexity of each of the Ruby defined methods.

Comment: I have never seen such an resource for any programming language. I doubt that developers are able to maintain such a list and keep it up-to-date...

Comment: I have seen that in the documentation of Eiffel/S. There the complexity of the methods was posted also. But Eiffel/S is long gone and hardly anyone knows what it was....

Comment: The c++ standard documents the complexity requirements for various methods (eg vector random access is O(1) with O(n) insertion (except at the end of the vector) etc

Comment: @FrederickCheung: It sometimes goes even further than that. IIRC, `std::sort` even mandates not just the *asymptotic* complexity as the collection size goes to infinity, but even the *exact* number of comparisons allowed for each `n`.